# How to implement Tomcat 8.0 container level authentication with Google OAuth2?

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat8, openid-connect, google-oauth

I have a Java web application deployed on AWS, which uses basic Tomcat authentication -

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

The application itself does not perform any authentication. All of that is handled by the container. I've been trying to do the same with Google OAuth2, where the application **does not** handle any authentication, but the container does, i.e., login with a Google or GSuite account. Is this possible?

[OpenID Connect Authenticator for Tomcat](https://github.com/boylesoftware/tomcat8-oidcauth) looked promising but when I logged in with it, it kept redirecting me to the login error page.

I followed these steps while trying to implement this on my `localhost` -

1. I downloaded and placed their [jar file](http://www.boylesoftware.com/maven/repo-os/org/bsworks/catalina/authenticator/oidc/tomcat8-oidcauth/) in `/tomcat-8/lib/`.
2. I created a Client ID with `Authorized JavaScript origins` as `https://localhost:8443` and `Authorized redirect URIs` as `https://localhost:8443/myapp/j_security_check`.
3. I setup `localhost` to use `https` on `port 8443`, since `hostBaseURI` requires it.
4. In my application's `web.xml`, I setup -

   `<security-constraint>
       <web-resource-collection>
           <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
           <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
           <url-pattern>/myapp/*</url-pattern>
       </web-resource-collection>
       <auth-constraint>
           <role-name>*</role-name>
       </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>`

   `<login-config>
       <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
       <realm-name>authTestWeb</realm-name>
       <form-login-config>
           <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/public/login.html</form-login-page>
           <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/public/login-error.html</form-error-page>
       </form-login-config>
   </login-config>`
5. In `context.xml`, I setup the `Valve` property as `<Valve className="org.bsworks.catalina.authenticator.oidc.OpenIDConnectAuthenticator" discoveryDocumentURL="https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration" clientId="xxxx" clientSecret="xxxx"/>`.
6. Placed the [Google Sign-In script](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) in `login.html`.

When I access `https://localhost:8443/myapp`, it prompts me for a Google username and password. When I login though, it briefly shows me a `Check Cookie` message and redirects to `login-error.html`.

What am I doing wrong here?

I've also thought about using [Philip Green II's module for Google OAuth 2](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/jaspic.html#Philip_Green_II's_module_for_Google_OAuth_2) but it looks like this is only available for Tomcat 8.5 and above. Unfortunately, AWS Elastic Beanstalk only has Tomcat 8.0 as the latest version.

So, how can I achieve Tomcat 8.0 container level authentication with Google OAuth2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that while Google OAuth2 is doing the authentication, authorization is still being handled by Tomcat, for which I had to create a role `myrole` and add a user to that, **where the username and password is the same**, i.e., both the username and password will be `email@example.com` -

`<user username="email@example.com" password="email@example.com" roles="myrole"/>`

Excerpt from their documentation - *"For the purpose of the OpenID Connect authenticator, the realm needs to be configured in such a way, that the password is always the same as the username (we still need the password due to limitations in the Tomcat API)."*

Additionally, I had to specify the role `myrole` in `<auth-constraint>` and `<security-role>` -

```
<security-constraint>
    ...
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>myrole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-role>
    <role-name>myrole</role-name>
</security-role>
```